# How can I block messenger spam on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, spam-prevention, messaging

I'm using Windows 8 with the Metro Messaging app. I can't work out how to block messenger spam, there doesn't seem to be an option either within the app or within the online live account settings. I'm getting at least 4 a day from random people who are not on my contact list.

Any help appreciated! I can only find guides online for the desktop app version of messaging.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm using Windows 8 on a Laptop - I think its Windows 8 Home or Professional version.

Comment: "Surely Microsoft have not removed the "block contact from unknown users feature"?" - It's not about removing, it's about not having added the feature (so far). Unfortunately, most Metro apps are still lagging far behind their Desktop counterparts (which admittedly have been around longer) in terms of customisability and even features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [**Messaging app for Windows FAQ**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/messaging-faq):

> **How do I block people from sending me messages?**
>
> You can't block people from the Messaging app—the app's just a hub that helps you stay in touch with your Messenger and Facebook friends.
>
> To delete a Messenger contact or prevent them from reaching you, go to your [contact list online](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=260954) and tap or click their name.
>
> To block Facebook friends, go to [Facebook's privacy section online](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260955).

Comment: And this my friends is why he has 12k rep

Comment: I'm trying because I want to put a bounty on my question with out losing privileges. I like superuser over overflow because you guys are a lot more relaxed with the "quality" of questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there was some more privacy features hidden somewhere as this is going to be a bit of a painful process.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's the answer nobody likes, but one of the easiest and simplest ways to deal with any kind of spam is to get a new e-mail address, username, phone number, whatever.

If you're getting that many messages a day, some real creeps have your info, best to abandon the account and start over with one they don't know about.

The only other alternative is to see if these is some way you can get a filter to allow ONLY people YOU approve to contact you, I don't know if windows 8 messaging has that feature or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for the option to say "Only allow messages from people on my contact list" but I can't find it. I'm not sure that changing email addresses will fix the problem - from what I can tell this is just random messenger spam? Seems kind of excessive to fix a missing privacy option by changing my email address and keeping the address itself private.

Comment: I wish there was an easy solution, but i know people who have done this, and it does help. its less random than you think, spammers work from lists of known e-mail addresses

Comment: @MDTGuy Windows Live Messenger?

Comment: @MDTGuy On a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I can't manage to get the Windows 8 phone emulator to download thus preventing me from seeing what you see. From what I can recommend however is that you try doing this

Settings -> Privacy -> settings -> find something like "Friends only". This should help. If it didn't tell me and I'll continue to attempt to get this emulator to download. Somehow the servers are down...

Comment: Why do you need the Windows 8 *phone emulator*? Just install Win8 in a VM like VirtualBox.

Comment: Because it seems he's using a mobile device?

Comment: Mobile device? Why would you think so? I guess you've not yet seen or used the Messaging App in Win8. See [here](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/mail-calendar-people-and/64a79953-cf0b-44f9-b5c4-ee5df3a15c63), [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/messaging-faq) and [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-chat-through-the-windows-8-messaging-app.html) for details. Your answer, if it deals with the desktop Messenger app, does not apply to the new Win8 Metro app in any way.

Comment: @Karan Earlier he said he could only find how to do it for the desktop. By saying this I assumed he ment that he needed it for his mobile device.

Comment: No, it's this weird Desktop/Metro dichotomy introduced in Win8. So far there was no alternative to Desktop apps in Windows, but that's no longer the case in Win8.

Comment: Sorry - Windows 8 on a Laptop. Not sure of the version of Windows 8 I should have included that, laptop is at work I will clarify once I'm back in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported that this problem does not seem to exist after the move to Skype.

If you are not already using Skype, and Skype is an acceptable solution, install Skype and see :
[How to permanently disable the Messaging App in Windows 8](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/16876-how-to-permanently-disable-the-messaging-app-in-windows-8).

In any case, if you are using the Messaging app, it will be [officially retired](http://blogs.skype.com/2013/02/15/skype-and-messenger-coming-together-the-next-chapter/) by April 8, 2013.